# Unable to create documents in Desktop Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, files, gnome-shell, desktop-icons

If I want to create a document in Ubuntu Desktop (using the mouse right button), I can't find this option.

[image]

However when I open Desktop through File Manager, I can find the option again!

[image]

Is there any explanation for this?
Is it a bug?
If possible, how to fix it?

Comment: This is because there is a huge changeover that took place: from the file-manager Nautilus handling the desktop item to a GNOME Shell extension called "desktop icons" handling them instead in 20.04. Refer to this for the official reasons provided to remove the desktop items handling feature from Nautilus: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/158